# IcCube - Facts Table not completely matching Dimension

Tags: olap, iccube

I have a facts table and a dimension table from two different sources. They are connected with an offer_id. But in the facts table there are offer_ids not found in the dimension table and vice versa.
Building the cube of course I get some 'no member found for key' error.

Is it possible, to get the cube done with a default offer_id where none is to be found? I didn't find an option to join those two tables withing IcCube (I hoped for a Table View) and a default I only seem to be able to set at a tables creation - but at that point I don't even know, which entries to change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see the 'Unknown Member' option in the Dimensions...
Thanks anyway.